# Qual a origem da expressão "não atremei "?

Tags: significado, expressões, regionalismo

Qual a origem da expressão "não atremei"?

Atremei significa ouvir em algumas regiões de Portugal. Será só regionalismo?

Muito utilizada  na Madeira

Comment: Curioso que nunca ouvi o verbo "atremer" ser usado. No dicionário indica ser [regionalismo da Madeira](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/Atremei) e as outras entradas indicam ser uma palavra de uso popular. Interessante a expressão.